# Can't install tamil package in magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, language-package, magento2.3.3

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ta_IN` package not listed in language so showing that error while we install new language included (lib/internal/Magento/Framework)

But there is no such folder

> /Magento/Framework

inside **lib/internal**

And there no custom packages available for **tamil**.

Is theres any custom packages to download **ta_IN** ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Goto `magento\vendor\magento\framework\Locale\Config.php`

Add entry to Tamil **'ta_IN'** inside protected $_allowedLocales = [];

```
$_allowedLocales = [
        'af_ZA', /*Afrikaans (South Africa)*/
        'ar_DZ', /*Arabic (Algeria)*/
        'ar_EG', /*Arabic (Egypt)*/
        'es_BO', /*Spanish (Bolivia)*/
         .
         .
        'ta_IN', /*Tamil (India) */
    ];
```

**Step 2:**

Run the following command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy ta_IN -f
```

Now you can configure the Tamil language for your store view.

**Store -> Configuration -> General -> Locale**

[image]

Comment: I have done the following above one which you told but i still have the problem.
I still get the error as shown below.


There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 426313092784

Comment: @Haerriz usually this exception is thrown when we setup a wrong DB configurations . you can this thread which discuss abut this exception in detail. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14207/exception-printing-is-disabled-by-default-for-security-reasons